# Need to find days difference between two org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime dates in java

Tags: java, threetenbp

I have two dates in an `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime` object. I need to find the difference between these two dates in terms of days.

Answer (score 44):

Use `org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit.between`:

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fromDate, toDate);
```

Comment: Just a note - if you want time difference in minutes/seconds, you need to use `LocalDateTime` and not `LocalDate`, otherwise you get an exception.